# How to make a grid layout in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, grid

I want to make a kind of grid layout (not scrollable) in an iOS app, similar to this:

[image]

I can do it using multiple `UIView` but that won't be a good solution. If I use `UICollectionView', I believe it will become scrollable? I want fixed grid items, which resize them according to screen size.

Any guidelines please?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901286/how-to-make-uicollectionviewflowlayout-itemsize-dynamic-for-screen-size

Comment: u can manage height and width of collection view cell according to screen size

Comment: @Ellen Thank you! Got it!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `collection view` with `scrolling and bouncing disable`.

It is all about your collectionview's flowlayout's item size.

You have to calculate item size receptively your screen's size.

And you can set that `item size` to `flowlayout` and can use that `flowlayou`t with your `collection view`.

For example, You can refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988028/how-do-i-define-the-size-of-a-collectionview-on-rotate).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want fixed 3x2 layout scaling to any screen size then multiple `UIView` is a good solution for this and exactly what you should do.

Also make a `RestaurantView` `UIView` subclass to configure and display the image/rating/title/description/etc details for each restaurant.

-

If you want the number of restaurants to change depending on screensize then use a `UICollectionView` with `ResturantCollectionViewCell` instead.